# Error in rep.int(sep, ncolumns - 1) : invalid 'times' value in bayesx function [R2BayesX package] in R

Tags: r, compiler-errors, geospatial, poisson, gam

I am trying to run a STAR model within the R2BayesX package using the bayesx function. My model works with the cases of leptospirosis in Colombia ('observed' and 'expected') by department in a quarterly assessment between the year 2007 and 2018.  In this model, I have entered a covaraible called 'humidity' that contains the relative humidity in each department by quarter. The temporal data I have set it with the first day of each quarter (2007-01-01 , 2007-04-01, ...) but inside the STFDF object I have numbered them from 1 to 48 inside the column 'num_trim', finally the ID of the departments I have identified them according to ID. the code I execute is the following:

```
bayesx_leptos_hum <- R2BayesX::bayesx(
      formula = observados~humedad + sx(num_trim, bs = "rw1") + 
        sx(ID , bs = "spatial" , map = graf_leptos),
      offset = log(leptos$esperados),
      family = "poisson" ,
      data = as(
      object = leptos,
      Class = "data.frame"
       )
     )
```

When running the code I get the following error:

```
`Error in rep.int(sep, ncolumns - 1) : invalid 'times' value`.
```